# How to improve query performance for multiple inner joins?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-optimization, qsqlquery

I have a query which is taking 1 minute to execute. After spending some time on the query I found there is some part that is actually causing the query to take the time.
Please see my comments below for the query mentioned.

Complete query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CSU.*, U.txtFirstName, U.txtLastName 
FROM
    tblCRMShallowUsers CSU (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
    tblUsers U (NOLOCK) ON CSU.PK_autUserID = U.PK_autUserID 
INNER JOIN 
    tblUserGroupLink UGL (NOLOCK) ON U.PK_autUserID = UGL.FK_lngUsersID 
INNER JOIN 
    tblModuleSecurityLinks MSL (NOLOCK) ON FK_lngModuleID = 28 
INNER JOIN 
    tblGroups G (NOLOCK) ON G.PK_autGroupID = MSL.FK_lngGroupID 
WHERE 
    MSL.lngRights > 0
    AND U.lngStatus > 19
    AND U.ysnAdminFlag = 0
    AND G.lngStatus > 19
    AND G.ysnFrontEndGroup = 0
    AND (UGL.FK_lngGroupID = MSL.FK_lngGroupID
         OR UGL.FK_lngGroupID = 2) 
ORDER BY 
    ysnHasAccess DESC, txtLastName, txtFirstName
```

Below joins are performing quickly in the above query:

```
INNER JOIN 
    tblUsers U (NOLOCK) ON CSU.PK_autUserID = U.PK_autUserID 
INNER JOIN 
    tblUserGroupLink UGL (NOLOCK) ON U.PK_autUserID = UGL.FK_lngUsersID 
INNER JOIN 
    tblModuleSecurityLinks MSL (NOLOCK) ON FK_lngModuleID = 28 
INNER JOIN 
    tblGroups G (NOLOCK) ON G.PK_autGroupID = MSL.FK_lngGroupID
```

Here's the AND part in the above query that is really slowing it down. When I remove this join it was working very fast but the result set is not the result that was coming earlier.(it returns more data)

```
AND (UGL.FK_lngGroupID = MSL.FK_lngGroupID
     OR UGL.FK_lngGroupID = 2)
```

I would really appreciate if you can show some direction to optimize the query or some example or other way of writing the same query.

Comment: Have you tried adding proper indexes to your tables?

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query i.e. add some lines of `create ...` and `insert...` to your code to give a foundation for testing and demonstrating.

Comment: Try a `UNION` query without DISTINCT.  Specify `ON G.PK_autGroupID = MSL.FK_lngGroupID` in the first `SELECT` and `ON UGL.FK_lngGroupID = 2` in the second `SELECT`.

Comment: @DanGuzman that should definitely help, make an answer of it!

Comment: @flaschenpost, I wouldn't go so far as to say it will definitely help but there's a good chance it will. I'll post it as an answer after the op confirms.

Comment: @DanGuzman You are absolutely right but I think you want to say `UGL.FK_lngGroupID = MSL.FK_lngGroupID` in the first select and 2nd select as you said in your above comment. Now the query is working in 0 seconds. This is shockingly working really very fast. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @user958269: many query optimizers can't use an index for "complex" conditions. When you split the query into two parts, and each part gets just a small subset of the table, then each part can access the index and is fast. the `X or Y` can not use the index and is slow.

Comment: @user958269, I added my comment as an answer along with your correction.

Comment: @flaschenpost Thanks for the explanation. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the optimal execution plan with each of the `OR` predicates differs, performance is improved by refactoring the single query as separate `SELECT` queries and a `UNION` operator. This allows the optimizer to choose the best plan for each query independently of the other.  `DISTINCT` is not needed since `UNION` removes duplicate rows from the result.

```
SELECT
    CSU.*, U.txtFirstName, U.txtLastName 
FROM
    tblCRMShallowUsers CSU (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
    tblUsers U (NOLOCK) ON CSU.PK_autUserID = U.PK_autUserID 
INNER JOIN 
    tblUserGroupLink UGL (NOLOCK) ON U.PK_autUserID = UGL.FK_lngUsersID 
INNER JOIN 
    tblModuleSecurityLinks MSL (NOLOCK) ON FK_lngModuleID = 28 
INNER JOIN 
    tblGroups G (NOLOCK) ON G.PK_autGroupID = MSL.FK_lngGroupID 
WHERE 
    MSL.lngRights > 0
    AND U.lngStatus > 19
    AND U.ysnAdminFlag = 0
    AND G.lngStatus > 19
    AND G.ysnFrontEndGroup = 0
    AND UGL.FK_lngGroupID = MSL.FK_lngGroupID
UNION
SELECT
    CSU.*, U.txtFirstName, U.txtLastName 
FROM
    tblCRMShallowUsers CSU (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
    tblUsers U (NOLOCK) ON CSU.PK_autUserID = U.PK_autUserID 
INNER JOIN 
    tblUserGroupLink UGL (NOLOCK) ON U.PK_autUserID = UGL.FK_lngUsersID 
INNER JOIN 
    tblModuleSecurityLinks MSL (NOLOCK) ON FK_lngModuleID = 28 
INNER JOIN 
    tblGroups G (NOLOCK) ON G.PK_autGroupID = MSL.FK_lngGroupID 
WHERE 
    MSL.lngRights > 0
    AND U.lngStatus > 19
    AND U.ysnAdminFlag = 0
    AND G.lngStatus > 19
    AND G.ysnFrontEndGroup = 0
    AND UGL.FK_lngGroupID = 2 
ORDER BY 
    ysnHasAccess DESC, txtLastName, txtFirstName;
```

On a side note, be aware than `NOLOCK` and the `READ_UNCOMMITTED` isolation level may cause rows to be skipped or duplicated during allocation order scans if data are updated while the query is running.  Dirty reads should be used only when concurrency is more important than correct results.

Answer (score 0):

@DanGuzman @flaschenpost  I was also trying with CTE approach to divide the joins into 2 seaprate things but it wasn't working and taking the same time as it was(1 minute). 
Could you please take a look at below query that I tried.

1. With CTE approach:  `With  UsersUserGroupLink AS(
              Select U.PK_autUserID, U.txtFirstName, U.txtLastName, U.lngStatus, U.ysnAdminFlag, UGL.FK_lngGroupID
              FROM tblUsers as U (NOLOCK)
              INNER JOIN tblUserGroupLink as UGL (NOLOCK)
              ON U.PK_autUserID = UGL.FK_lngUsersID 
              ), 
   GroupsModuleSecurityLinks AS(Select MSL.lngRights, G.lngStatus, G.ysnFrontEndGroup, MSL.FK_lngGroupID   From

   tblModuleSecurityLinks as MSL (NOLOCK)
          INNER JOIN tblGroups as G (NOLOCK)
          ON G.PK_autGroupID = MSL.FK_lngGroupID AND MSL.FK_lngModuleID = 28   )  (SELECT DISTINCT CSU.*, UsersUserGroupLink.txtFirstName,    UsersUserGroupLink.txtLastName FROM UsersUserGroupLink  Inner join

   tblCRMShallowUsers as CSU  ON UsersUserGroupLink.PK_autUserID =

   CSU.PK_autUserID Inner join GroupsModuleSecurityLinks ON

   GroupsModuleSecurityLinks.FK_lngGroupID =

   UsersUserGroupLink.FK_lngGroupID  or
   UsersUserGroupLink.FK_lngGroupID    = 2 WHERE
   GroupsModuleSecurityLinks.lngRights > 0 AND
   UsersUserGroupLink.lngStatus > 19 AND
   UsersUserGroupLink.ysnAdminFlag    = 0 AND
   GroupsModuleSecurityLinks.lngStatus > 19   AND
   GroupsModuleSecurityLinks.ysnFrontEndGroup = 0) ORDER BY
   ysnHasAccess    DESC, txtLastName, txtFirstName`